# ARCGis FeatureLayer not visible on version 3.2+

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have a system which is currently implemented in ARCGIS version 3.18 however, when upgrading to version 3.2+ the FeatureLayer are no longer visible.

They become visible when changing it to a ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer however, then the info window is then not visible with the dynamic map server.

Did anyone have this issue before?

```
var fLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://..../MapServer/0", { mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND });
   map.addLayer(fLayer);
```

Comment: Can you add some code to see how are you creating the layers?

Comment: updated question accordingly

Comment: You code seems correct, it must be something else. You will need to add more context to the question, like when you are creating and adding the layer?. I am guessing the service is private if not add it also. The library is old and is not even in the latest version, so it is even older, but it is weird to me that the change would affect something like this, again it must be related to the context of creation.

Comment: The code within the complete application is much longer and it is being activated using a TOC to show and hide the layer. However, the above is the simple version which I'm using to test to make sure that nothing is interfering with the layer. Basically I'm just initializing a map and adding a basemap on it then adding the layer... very basic implementation to test. Could it be an issue coming from the publishing of the layer?

Comment: You did well in simplify to test the service. Check the request response of the feature layer in the test implementation, what it look like? anything weird? 0 results?.

Comment: Nothing strange.. same response from both api versions...